# Converting existing string field type to array field type in database | Rails + PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, carrierwave

I'm using Ruby on Rails with Postgresql and had a String db field for attachment. Now I support multi file upload and need to convert my Attachment String db field to String Array so that I can host multiple files.

**How do I convert the existing "String" db field to "String Array" using Rails Console?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't convert the "String" db field into a "String Array". What you're looking for is a serializer. Do the following in your model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :attachment, Array
end

# Try in rails console
Post.find 117
#=> #<Post id: 117, attachment: ["11.jpg", "22.jpg", "33.jpg"] ...>
```

You can save provide an array while saving it, and it will convert it to string and store it & while extracting it will convert the string to an array and return you the array

Also you might want to rename your column from `attachment` to `attachments` since its will contain an array.

Comment: WOW! That actually worked! I wasted over 1 week with many hours for it with no result! Thank you mate! I'm going to read and learn more about this serialize!

Comment: Yes, you can even have json, hash etc. You can even create your custom structures by having `load` and `dump` as class methods in your serializer. Good luck